# Adding a where clause with no divisions leads to a "divide by zero" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table with three columns: `companyId`, `date` and `price`.

I want to get each company's return from their start to their end date (`price_end / price_start`). Some companies can have data errors which gives them a zero starting price, so I need to handle that to avoid divide-by-zero errors:

```sql
SELECT companyId
     , lastPrice / firstPrice AS gain
FROM (
    SELECT companyId
         , SUM(IIF(firstDay = 1, price, 0)) AS firstPrice
         , SUM(IIF(lastDay  = 1, price, 0)) AS lastPrice
    FROM (
        SELECT companyId
             , price
             , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY companyId
                            ORDER BY date) AS firstDay
             , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY companyId
                            ORDER BY date DESC) AS lastDay
        FROM Foo
    ) x
    GROUP BY companyId
) x
WHERE firstPrice != 0  -- avoid divide-by-zero errors!
```

This works just fine. However, I've also noticed some companies have absurd returns, clearly due to some more data errors or something weird happening to them. So I want to discard such cases.

However, if I wrap the above in a subquery and then add an additional `WHERE` statement to discard excessive returns (arbitrarily set to `> 10`), I get a divide-by-zero error:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT companyId
         , lastPrice / firstPrice AS gain
    FROM (
        SELECT companyId
             , SUM(IIF(firstDay = 1, price, 0)) AS firstPrice
             , SUM(IIF(lastDay  = 1, price, 0)) AS lastPrice
        FROM (
            SELECT companyId
                 , price
                 , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY companyId
                                ORDER BY date) AS firstDay
                 , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY companyId
                                ORDER BY date DESC) AS lastDay
            FROM Foo
        ) x
        GROUP BY companyId
    ) x
    WHERE firstPrice != 0  -- avoid divide-by-zero errors!
) x
WHERE gain < 10  -- should discard excessive returns, but get divide-by-zero
```

I unfortunately can't figure out how to create a reprex, but I have found an example case where this happens: it's a company which has a `NULL` initial price (a data error, obviously). However, this `NULL` is converted to a zero in the `SUM(...) AS firstPrice`, so I'd guess it's not actually relevant, especially since that means the data is discarded at the next step due to the `WHERE firstPrice != 0`.

But here's what happens with and without the `WHERE gain < 10` clause:

[image]

Without the `gain < 10` filter, the result is empty, as expected, simply throwing a warning due to the conversion of the `NULL` to a zero in the `SUM()`.

But then with the gain filter:

[image]

For completeness, here's the output for each of the subqueries, from the deepest outwards:

`SELECT ... FROM Foo`

[image]

`SELECT companyId, SUM(...) AS firstPrice, ... FROM ( ... )`

[image]

`SELECT companyId, lastPrice / firstPrice AS gain FROM (...) WHERE firstPrice !=0`

[image]

---

Now, obviously I can fix this by adding a `WHERE price IS NOT NULL` to the innermost subquery. But my question is **why does this happen at all?**

I've seen other questions being answered with "the optimizer can change the order of WHERE operations", but does that even apply across subqueries? Does the `NULL value is eliminated...` warning have anything to do with this?

If relevant, I'm on SQL Server 2014.

Comment: If you are saying that a `price` with a zero value is corrupted data that should be discarded, then I would discard it as soon as possible in the most inner subquery by adding `WHERE price <> 0`.

Comment: `SUM(IIF(firstDay = 1, price, 0)) AS firstPrice` won't convert a null price to zero. `SUM(IIF(1 = 1, null, 0))` evaluates to null.

Comment: You could also wrap your denominator in a NULLIF()  ..,    Numerator /   NULLIF( Denominator,0)

Comment: Now, if the starting price is null/zero, what do you want to consider as the "starting price" then? The next available row maybe, or do you prefer to discard the whole company?

Comment: The computation in the Select list can get pushed down before the filter that discards zeroes. Use CASE or NULLIF to be safe even if it does get evaluated with a zero

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm aware of that and I'll certainly do it. I'm just trying to understand this behavior (why a subquery with an empty result throws a divide-by-zero error if the outer query makes a non-division WHERE filter)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft At least in SQL Server 2014, SUM() does seem to discard NULLS (that's even what causes the warning shown in the OP). [Here's a more explicit demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqe79.png).

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yes, I'm aware of how to solve the issue, I'm just trying to understand this odd behavior, where adding a seemingly harmless WHERE statement causes a completely unrelated error.

Comment: Because the additional `WHERE` clause has caused the data engine to change it's order of operations, @Wasabi, meaning that a divide by zero was encountered. Generally, I feel that lots of subqueries like that can make things "messy". Perhaps CTEs would be better, or multiple `CROSS APPLY`s to do the calculations.

Comment: @MartinSmith So the optimizer can actually move operations around across subqueries? I'd already understood that one can't trust the order of operations in a WHERE clause. That's why I did `WHERE firstPrice != 0` and only later `WHERE gain < 10` in its parent query as opposed to `WHERE firstPrice != 0 AND lastPrice / firstPrice < 10`, since I can't trust that it'll discard cases with `firstPrice != 0` before trying the division. But I'd always assumed subqueries were a means to force a certain order of operations on the optimizer.

Comment: @Larnu as I just wrote in my comment to MartinSmith, I wasn't aware the optimizer could move operations even across subqueries. I'd always thought they were a way to force an order of operations. And should I take your suggestion of CTEs to mean that CTEs are better ways of setting this order of operations? Feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: The optimiser can move expressions round the tree, including pushing them into CTEs or similar. There used to be a Connect item discussing all this but lost when the Connect site was shut down http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors